# How to hide Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I hide `Edit | Quick Edit | Trash | View  and Add New` in wordpress, only in custom post type, I am doing it in this way and it's hiding in all post types

```
 add_action('admin_head', 'hide_category_buttons');

 function hide_category_buttons() {
   echo '<style>
    .row-actions {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

.page-title-action {
   visibility: hidden;
 }

  </style>';
 }
```

Is there any way to not have these things when we create custom post. For example when we create custom post type we type labels array and if we do not want to have name or menu name we just don't add in array and that dose not display in dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use below line of code in your functions.php,

```
function remove_quick_edit( $actions, $post) {
  if ($post->post_type =="CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_SLUG"){
    unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    unset($actions['edit']);
    unset($actions['trash']);
    unset($actions['view']);
    }
  return $actions;
}
add_filter('post_row_actions','remove_quick_edit',10,2);
```

*CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_SLUG -> replace your custom post type slug

you can add any other value need to hide use this:

```
 unset($actions['view']);
```

Replae the value you want instead of *view